# Search in Address[] if exist the same address sender

Tags: solidity, arrays, address.transfer

I want to check if the Address sender is already in `Address[]`. If `true`, then do not allow this address to make the payment.

```
Contract Hello {
  address[] internal Pool;

  function () public payable {
  require(msg.value * 10 == 1 ether);

  if (msg.sender already exist in address[]){
    revert();
    Rejected();

  } else {
    Pool.push(msg.sender);
  }
 }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: did you get it solved?

Comment: Yes, with the coment below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As i feel easy way is to keep a mapping that would store Boolean value `true` for already in addresses.

```
Contract Hello {
  address[] internal Pool;
  mapping (address => boolean) private oldUsers;


  function () public payable {
  require(msg.value * 10 == 1 ether);

  //check for old users
  if (oldUsers[msg.sender]){
    revert();
    Rejected();

  } else {
    Pool.push(msg.sender);
    // enter as an old user
    oldUsers[msg.sender] = true;
  }
 }
}
```